# How to Assign a Default Value when joining the table if one column having Zero value in sql server?

Tags: mysql

I have a task, retrieving a value by joining two tables. The thing is I have `DomainID` column in the main table which is having 0 value for some rows. Here I'm retrieving **DomainName** which is present in another table. While joining the tables, the result table is displaying no records. I mean due to that column effecting the result table. Here I have to display some value if DomainID is zero. How can I do that?

My Effort is:

```
SELECT 
    A.UserID,
    A.UserName,
    A.Fullname,
    A.EmailID,
    A.DateOfReg,
    A.MobileNo,
    A.DOB,    
    B.RoleName,
    C.DomainID
FROM tr_m_users A 
INNER JOIN tr_m_roles B 
ON B.RoleID=A.RoleID
INNER JOIN tr_m_domains D 
ON 
**Coalesce(C.DomainID,'(novalue)')=Coalesce(A.DomainID,'(novalue)')**
OR
**Isnull(C.DomainID,'novalue')=Isnull(A.DomainID,'novalue')**
LIMIT 1000
```

In the query above I used the `COALESCE` function and the `ISNULL` function to replace a value instead of zero. But I get no results. Please help me. If I remove the DomainID column from the join I am getting 1000 records, but when I placing the DomainID I'm getting no records simply displaying 0 records.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes now i tried with Left Inner join..Got the result..Thank u for giving suggestion

Comment: You state that table tr_m_users does have values of `0` or `zero`. Do you mean the special value `NULL` instead? And am I correct that you need the correct join condition for the join with table `tr_m_domains`. By the way you've got the alias name wrong: it got to be `C` not `D`.

Comment: Hi VMai
The prblm is sorted out by using Left Join instead of Innerjoin.